# Convert Dfa to RE

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I want to covert this DFA to RE:

[image]

I converted and this is my result: 1*+1*2+21*, but I test it and give wrong result.

This dfa describe "any strings(lambda) but not contain 22". 
Please help me about!

Comment: The picture is not a DFA: two outgoing edges with "1" in state "aa". Without the loop "1" at "aa" the automaton represents "any strings but not contain 22" as wanted.

Comment: Converting finite automata to regular expressions is a standard technique that is covered in every textbook and set of lecture notes on the subject. If you have a specific question about the techniques, please make that question clearer; otherwise, there's not much point in somebody writing out another explanation of how to do it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Keep in mind that we have reference questions for just this purpose. :)

Comment: I edit question!

Comment: @Raphael Ta. Forgot we have one on this.

Comment: @FaffafaTrtrtrtrt Please stop trying to change the automaton in the question! If you're the person who originally asked the question, please contact the Stack Exchange admins to get the two accounts linked together. If you're not, please don't make edits that fundamentally change what the question says. And, if your edit is rejected, DO NOT submit the same edit again. That just wastes everybody's time.